# Count occurrence HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, frequency

I'm trying to count the number of diseases a day by using hashmap:

```
public static main(String[] args){
 Disease cholera=new Disease("cholera");
 Disease dengue=new Disease("dengue");

 List<Diagnosis> diagnoses = Arrays.asList(
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 0), // registered cholera on day 0
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 0),
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 1),
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 1),
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 2),
            new Diagnosis(cholera, 2)
    );
   
   printFreq(diagnosis);

}
  
public static void printFreq(List<Diagnosis> diagnoses) {
    Map<Diagnosis, Integer> hm = new HashMap();
    for (Diagnosis x : diagnoses) {

        if (!hm.containsKey(x)) {
            hm.put(x, 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(x, hm.get(x) + 1);
        }
    }
```

But if I call printFreq(diagnoses) I get:{{cholera, 0}=1, {cholera, 1}=1, {cholera, 2}=1, {cholera, 0}=1, {dengue, 0}=1, {cholera, 1}=1, {cholera, 2}=1}. How can I fix this to {{cholera,0}=2,{dengue0}=1,{cholera,1}=2,{cholera,2}=2}}

I'm not allowed to change the Diagnosis or Disease class but this is how they look like:

```
public class Disease {

private final String name;

public Disease(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Disease disease = (Disease) o;

    return name.equals(disease.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Diagnosis:

```
 public class Diagnosis {

private final Disease disease;
private final int day;

public Diagnosis(Disease disease, int day) {
    this.disease = disease;
    this.day = day;
}

public Disease getDisease() {
    return disease;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" + disease + ", " + day + "}";
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should really have a `Map<Disease, Integer>` rather than a `Map<Diagnosis, Integer>`. After all, you're trying to count the number of *diseases* a day...

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually want to count how many times a certain disease is registered each day, so not just the total. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my description.

Comment: It would really help if you'd include the *expected* results - at the moment I'm finding it very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet My understanding is that OP wants grouping to disease reported per day. I based my answer on this. So, Day 0 - Cholera - (count) etc. OP should correct my understanding.

Comment: @sushant: The way to make this clear is for there to be a clear example in the question though. And if there's more than one disease, it would really help if the example showed that too... currently it's *only* showing Cholera. I can't tell how the OP expects to represent (in the input data *or* output data) "On day 0, we diagnosed 3 cases of cholera and 2 of covid".

Comment: @JonSkeet I completely agree. I see that the expected output has {dengue0}=1. So based on this, my guess is that OP has a typo in the code, or has missed adding `new Diagnosis(dengue, 0)` to the `diagnoses` list.

Comment: @sushant Sorry I missed to add new Diagnosis(dengue,0). So basically my original problem is to write a function public Collection<String> findEpidemics(List<Diagnosis> diagnoses, int k, int n) that determines if a disease is a epidemic, and returns a list of the diseases that are epidemic. We say a disease is a epidemic if it occurs more than n times during k consecutive days. That's why I was trying to write a method that finds the frequencies for each day, and got stuck with my hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a wrapper class to make life easier. In this code I have a wrapper class `DiagnosisMetric` that wraps the `Diagnosis` class.
Following is the new implementation of the `printFreq` function.

```
    public static void printFreq(List<Diagnosis> diagnoses) {
        Map<DiagnosisMetric, Long> collect = diagnoses.stream().
             collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DiagnosisMetric::new, counting()));
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
```

And, following is the wrapper class. Notice that I have implemented `equals` and `hashCode` as per the requirement.

```
    public static class DiagnosisMetric {
      private Diagnosis diagnosis;

        public DiagnosisMetric(Diagnosis s) {
            this.diagnosis = s;
        }

        public Diagnosis getDiagnosis() {
            return diagnosis;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            DiagnosisMetric that = (DiagnosisMetric) o;
            return diagnosis.getDisease().getName().
              equals(that.getDiagnosis().getDisease().getName())
                    && diagnosis.getDay() == that.getDiagnosis().getDay();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(diagnosis.getDay(), 
                   diagnosis.getDisease().getName());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String disease = diagnosis.getDisease().getName();
            int day = diagnosis.getDay();
            return "{" + disease + ", " + day + "}";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An ad-hoc solution which does not require storing the intermediate map with `Diagnosis` key (which cannot be used as a map key without properly implemented `hashCode` and `equals` as mentioned earlier) is like this:

- use a raw list containing `diagnosis.day` and `disease.name` as a key wrapper in `Collectors.groupingBy`
- calculate the frequencies (e.g. using `Collectors.summingInt`)
- use `Supplier<Map>` to provide a tree map sorted by the list contents
- print the stats

```java
diagnoses.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        d -> Arrays.asList(d.getDay(), d.getDisease().getName()),
        () -> new TreeMap<List<?>, Integer> (Comparator
            .comparingInt((List k) -> (Integer) k.get(0))
            .thenComparing((List k) -> (String) k.get(1))
        ),
        Collectors.summingInt(d -> 1)
    )) // Map<List, Integer> created here
    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " = " + v));
```

Output:

```
[0, cholera] = 2
[0, dengue] = 1
[1, cholera] = 2
[2, cholera] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this what we need to do is to override the `hashCode` and `equals` method for the `Diagnosis` class, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Diagnosis diagnosis = (Diagnosis) obj;
    return this.day == diagnosis.day && this.disease == diagnosis.disease;
}
    
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    char[] charArr = this.disease.toString().toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        sum += charArr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Also you need to override `equals` method of the `Disease` class, here is code for that:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Disease disease = (Disease) obj;
    return this.disease.equalsIgnoreCase(disease.toString());
}
```